# How can I monitor if My Chrome Extension has been enabled after being in disabled state?

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-extension, google-chrome-devtools

Let's say if an extension has been disabled and enabled.
Currently my extension is not doing anything in this scenario(Ideally it should resume functioning as it does when the first time it was installed)

I tried having look at OnEnabled from "management" api but apparently that works only for monitoring other extensions.
Is there any way of detecting it for my own extension? Wondering how it works for other extensions.

Comment: There's no such event. The only solution is to use a persistent background script so it'll run immediately after enabling the extension.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but I am still not sure how other extensions just resumes working after disabling and enabling the extension.

Comment: It depends on what the extension does so you'll need to describe it in details to get further help. BTW ManifestV3 service worker properly wakes up on re-enabling so see if you can rewrite the extension.

Answer (score 0):

`chrome.runtime.onStartup.addListener(function(){})` runs when an extension is naturally started up (like when the browser first opens). I believe you could have a way to put something in the background script which could check whether this listener was called.